# My question was flagged as a duplicate when it wasn't a true duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I don't usually worry about downvotes, but I'm now genuinely confused. I posted this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273633/how-do-i-use-a-decorator-located-in-another-file

I tried to clarify the intent as best as possible. It was flagged as a duplicate, but the duplicate it was flagged as does not answer my question. It was then repeatedly downvoted without any explanation of what I was doing wrong.

Frankly, I just want to know what I'm doing wrong so I can not make that same mistake in the future. Was I in error, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't write much Python so perhaps I'm missing something obvious but it seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @MikeC The OP does not include in the question all the code necessary to reproduce the problem. I've copied the code, added the necessary `import` statements at the start (that are missing from the question but would *not* cause the error the OP is reporting) and **I cannot reproduce the problem.**

Comment: @Louis Now **that** is a problem. Pro-tip Ares: make sure you *always* include enough code for someone to reproduce your problem. Write the tiniest possible program that produces the problem and share that.

Comment: Am I missing something? What `import` statements are missing? They're in the question, right? I'm going to reproduce this with a clean slate.

Comment: @Ares You are not importing `time`, and you have to create `logger` somehow. (I've supposed, as is the norm, that it is created from the `logging` module.)

Comment: `time` is correctly imported in the actual file. `logger` is created properly as well. That said, I believe I have found the actual issue. It's different but related, should I post another question or edit this one?

Comment: @Ares Well, as I said, even if `time` or `logger` were in fact the issue (which I did not assume they were), it would not explain the error you are reporting in your question. This question being in the state it is in and given that you have received no useful answers, I would edit the question rather than post a new one.

Comment: The best thing would be to add an answer to your question that details exactly what was wrong and why you got hoodwinked into thinking it was something else.  You might get some upvotes on the question for a good answer that describes, for future people with the same problem, how you solved it.  Don't rewrite the question based on the answer, but do think about rewording the title to attract people who might have the same problem you did, if possible.  You might also add some details they may search for at the bottom of your question as well.

Comment: _@Ares_ Well, you did so now following @Will's advice, but unfortunately your question has been closed as a duplicate at almost the same time. Now you'll need to invest in the question qualifying it not to be a duplicate.

Comment: I still have a question, peripherally related, so I asked it as a new question. This time, hopefully it's easier to understand, and I'm not using any code I wrote for any purpose other than demonstrating the error. I suspect it would be a losing battle to try and get that question reopened, especially since it was flagged as a duplicate. The linked question is a dubious duplicate at best.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something actually descriptive of what you're asking. Your current title is simply click-bait. Titles should describe the question or problem in a way that will be relevant to a future reader who sees it in a search result without having to open the post. The same title requirements apply here that apply to the main SO site. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite What would be a better title? I had the same thought when crafting the question but I'm really not sure what would be more descriptive.

Comment: I don't know, because I don't see how your question isn't a duplicate of the indicated post, so I'm not sure what you're asking. At the very least, you could have said *I saw [this post]* and linked to the indicated duplicate, and explained why how and why it didn't answer your question. I *do* know that if I search for information, and I get back 50 questions that all have variations on "What's wrong with my post/question/answer/code?", it's not going to be helpful to me. *What's wrong with this question?* is totally vague and meaningless without opening the post, seeing the link, etc.

Comment: I updated the title, it's the closest I could come up with. It's my opinion that as a result of the way I structured my question (and the actual underlying issue) that the dupehammer was incorrectly applied in this case. It's mostly resolved, if not a giant mess.

Comment: Here's another thing, though: your answer and new question **still don't replicate the error**. If that was the problem you'd have seen `NameError`, not `ImportError`, to start with. I think you should just delete the first question, and ask a new one (with a MCVE! If you're talking about imports, show a minimal file and directory structure, for example) if you manage to recreate the issue.

Comment: I want to highlight that given that your problem about **imports** the following are **essential information** in order to diagnose the problem: 1) The name of *all* the files you are using (the importer and importee files) 2) The relative directories of this files 3) The current working directory from which you are executing the program.  Without this information we can come up with dozens of ways in which such error could be triggered simply due to path issues.

Comment: Define 'true duplicate' :)

Comment: @Ares I have had my questions down-voted before because I did not include all the relevant source code.  A complete compendium of every piece of code isn't necessary but everything that describes the question.  As a checklist, as yourself the following:  Will someone answering my question ask `where is the...?` and include as much as you believe is needed.  If you take these measures, then the response will be the answer you need.

Comment: Agreed, the question wasn't well formed. We can see the dispute on Meta unfolding though, since some people asked me to edit and answer my own question (I did)

but of course, after that happened the question was deleted. So entirely a moot point to do that. I ended up asking another question anyways.

Comment: @Mushy, no, what you are describing is not an MCVE. It seems very unfair to expect every visitor to the question take time to debug code that the asker has not even posted in a compilable state.

Comment: @RJFalconer RJ, I'm not proposing all code but certainly all relevant code to help the responder to understand the problem.  In essence I'm suggesting a properly added MCVE because not always does the responder want to guess at what the question is.

Comment: I think there's a valuable lesson here:
The problem was _not_ the question I was asking. It was something completely different. But the rapid dupehammer led to confusion. 
It reminds me of some of my experiences working IT. The user does not know or may not know fully what their problem is. That's on me, certainly. Of course, SO users are _not_ tech support. You are not detectives the way IT employees are. I think the lesson here is if you ask a question, make really sure that's the question you're asking. If you're answering it, make sure that you're targeting the real problem the user has.

Comment: It is so sad to see from you doing to me exactly the same what you suffered only 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score -5):

There does seem to a push towards downvoting questions repeatedly.   One can view it as the competing wishes to:

- provide helpful answers
- create a permanent knowledge base

These two are often in conflict.   Human nature will seize on the conflict and form 'us versus the idiots' mentality.

Comment: I don't think these would contradict. To me, the contradiction is that you invest working hours to collect reputation points. We are here all addicts of the green rectangle, it could be some like a gamblers addiction. It makes also the mood so bad on the metas. It is not a normal community, it is a community of gambling addicts in an intellectual trap.

Comment: We are not all such addicts, though it is hard to find an addict of any vice not claiming "everyone does it".   As one item of evidence, this post has a mild critique of the addiction and was immediately downvoted to -3.

Comment: Don't worry, -3 is not so bad. I have post here even below -50. And, what's then? It doesn't affect your reputation. It is only a psychological pressure. Btw, although I don't agree your literal statement, I wish to reward the unique viewpoints, so here is an up.